# htaccess redirect to Wordpress - 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Good afternoon,
I am having an issue with wordpress. I access to page123.domain.com and the .htaccess redirects it to `domain.com/wordpress?pagename=page123`.
Then i get the wordpress 404 page. I made a `die(print_r($_GET))` and it writes

`Array ( [pagename] => page123 )`

My question is : if I access directly to wordpress?pagename=page123 it works, why this is not working properly?
Do I have to edit some of the wordpress php files?

Comment: Is page123.domain.com registered in your dns, or does your dns know how to handle this?

Comment: Can you paste the .htaccess code you're using? - it's hard to tell with the information provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. After spending some time searching for an answer for this matter, i have noticed that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` was sligtly different than what it was supposed to be (instead of /devl2t/index.php/?pagename=teste was only /devl2t).
So the resolution was to manually edit the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] on the index.php

Answer (score 0):

This only can be related with 3 root causes:

- your .htaccess file
- wordpress plugin that is rewriting the get variable based on the subdomain
- a rewrite directive of you host company (RewriteOptions Inherit), or another apache directive that is taking control

You need to specify if this print_r($_GET) is on the theme, or on wordpress index.php(accurate since its the starting point) and check your .htaccess (it can be inherited)